# Chart.js How to set line height only to the points?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

How to set line height only until points? I have used 'gridLines: display:false' but it hides all lines. Here on image below how it should be

[image]

Comment: It's a good question, but it's a drawn canvas, I don't think you can change it :/ There are no options available to do that, and it can't be done manually to my knowledge. You do have [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties) tho the possible options available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a native option in Chart.js but you can implement it yourself via plugin. See the annotations in the below code.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'series 1',
      data: [0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false, // must be false since we're going to draw our own 'gridlines'!
          color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, .2)', // can still set the colour.
          lineWidth: 5 // can still set the width.
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  plugins: [{ // this is the magical bit :)
    afterRender: function(c, options) {
      let meta = c.getDatasetMeta(0),
        max;
      c.ctx.save();
      c.ctx.strokeStyle = c.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.color;
      c.ctx.lineWidth = c.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.lineWidth;
      c.ctx.beginPath();
      meta.data.forEach(function(e) {
        if (max == undefined || c.config.data.datasets[0].data[e._index] > max) {
          max = c.config.data.datasets[0].data[e._index];
        }
        c.ctx.moveTo(e._model.x, meta.dataset._scale.bottom);
        c.ctx.lineTo(e._model.x, e._model.y);
      });
      c.ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
      c.ctx.textAlign = 'right';
      c.ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      c.ctx.fillText('Max value: ' + max, c.width - 10, 10);
      c.ctx.stroke();
      c.ctx.restore();
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: OMG , you did it! I thought it's impossible . You are genius , thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please help me with one  more question , how to display max value like in the picture on top right corner?

Comment: @YerlanYeszhanov That's fairly straightforward. See my edit.

Comment: Hi! could you please check this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53961144/chartjs-how-to-set-max-labels-for-x-axis