# ChartJS How to set max labels for X axis?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I receive data for chart from an array , where I stored dates from 2016 , 1 to 2018 , 12 . In chart it displays all month for 3 years. But I need to display only for 1 year. Any ideas?

Here i'm passing an array and changing unit for month, also displayFormats

```
chartHour.config.data.datasets[0].data = array
chartHour.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].time = {
    unit: "month",
    stepSize: 1,
    displayFormats: {
      month: "MMM",
    },
  }
```

Comment: "In chart it displays all month for 3 years. But I need to display only for 1 year." You mean display only a maximum of 12 entries from 2016-2018 or display only the monthly data for a specific year like 2017 only?

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac  for a specific year like 2017 only!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by defining the `min` and `max` values under the `time` key.

> If `min` or `max` is defined, this will override the data minimum or maximum respectively. See [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-formats) for more info.

```
chartHour.config.options.scales.xAxes[0] = {
  type: "time",
  time: {
    min: "2017-01-01",
    max: "2017-12-01",
    displayFormats: {
      day: "MMM YY"
    }
  }
};
```

See working example below.

```js
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
const years = [2016, 2017, 2018];

const labels = [];
const dataSet = [];
years.forEach((year, index) => {
  months.forEach((month, monthIndex) => {
    const date = moment(`${month} ${year}`, "MMM YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    labels.push(date);
    dataSet.push({
      x: date,
      y: (monthIndex + 12) * (index + 1)
    });
  });
});

var data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    pointRadius: 0,
    label: "Positive",
    lineTension: 0,
    data: dataSet,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)"
  }]
};
var options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      type: "time",
      distribution: 'series',
      time: {
        min: "2017-01-01",
        max: "2017-12-01",
        displayFormats: {
          day: 'MMM YY'
        }
      },
      ticks: {
        source: "labels"
      },
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      }
    }]
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
```