# Chart.JS multiple plugins do not operate

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I am working with chart.js and am trying to add 2 plugins to the same chart, but when applied, both of the plugins disappear and there is no direct error in the console.

Does anyone know how to implement two plugins to the same graph?

[First pulgin](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/)

[Second plugin referance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721661/chart-js-how-to-set-line-height-only-to-the-points)

Basically, the graph has to show data labels on a line chart and at the same time, draw yAxis lines, but only starting from the points on the line chart.

For some reason, the chart will not show either of them when both are applied.

```
    Chart.helpers.merge(Chart.defaults.global.plugins.datalabels, {
        color : '#ffffff'
    })
    // Chart.plugins.unregister(ChartDataLabels);
    // var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // / plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    // options: {
    // // ...
    // }
    // })
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type : 'line',

        // The data for our dataset
        data : {
            labels : [ '', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', '' ],
            datasets : [ {
                label : 'My first dataset',
                borderWidth : 3,
                borderColor : 'rgb(255,0, 0)',
                data : data1,
            } ]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options : {
            elements : {
                point : {
                    radius : 3
                }
            },
            legend : {
                display : false,
                labels : {
                    fontColor : "white",
                    fontSize : 18
                }
            },
            scales : {
                yAxes : [ {
                    ticks : {
                        fontSize : 0,
                        beginAtZero : false,
                        max : 40,
                    },
                    gridLines : {
                        display : false,
                        drawBorder : false,
                    }
                } ],
                xAxes : [ {
                    ticks : {
                        fontColor : "white",
                        fontSize : 14,
                        beginAtZero : 0,
                    },
                    gridLines : {
                        display : false,
                    }
                } ]
            },
             plugins : [ { // this is the magical bit :)
                        afterRender : function(c, options) {
                            let
                            meta = c.getDatasetMeta(0), max;
                            c.ctx.save();
                            c.ctx.strokeStyle = c.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.color;
                            c.ctx.lineWidth = c.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.lineWidth;
                            c.ctx.beginPath();
                            meta.data
                                    .forEach(function(e) {
                                        if (max == undefined
                                                || c.config.data.datasets[0].data[e._index] > max) {
                                            max = c.config.data.datasets[0].data[e._index];
                                        }
                                        c.ctx.moveTo(e._model.x,
                                                meta.dataset._scale.bottom);
                                        c.ctx
                                                .lineTo(e._model.x,
                                                        e._model.y);
                                    });
                            c.ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
                            c.ctx.textAlign = 'right';
                            c.ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                            c.ctx.fillText('Max value: ' + max,
                                    c.width - 10, 10);
                            c.ctx.stroke();
                            c.ctx.restore();
                        }
                    } ],
            tooltips : {
                callbacks : {
                    label : function(tooltipItem) {
                        console.log(tooltipItem)
                        return tooltipItem.yLabel;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });



var data1 = [ 1, 9, 12, 3, 15, 8, 2, -5, 3, 4, 5, 7 ];
    myChart(data1);
```

HTML .js code

```
<script src="js/chart.js"></script>
    <!-- data label .js -->
<script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.5.0"></script>
    <!-- yAxis lines .js -->
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {        
    type : 'line',          
    data : {
        labels : [ '', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', '' ],
        datasets : [ {
            label : 'My first dataset',
            borderWidth : 1,
            borderColor : 'rgb(255,0, 0)',
            data : [ 1, 9, 12, 3, 15, 8, 2, -5, 3, 4, 5, 7 ],
             datalabels: {
          align: 'end',
          anchor: 'end',        
                  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 120, 12, .2)',
borderRadius: 20
             }
        }]
    },        
    options : {
        scales : {
   xAxes : [ {
    gridLines : {
                    display : false,      
     color: 'rgba(255, 120, 12, .2)',      
     lineWidth: 5
                }
   } ],
   yAxes : [{
       gridLines : {
                    display : false,                        
     color: 'rgba(255, 120, 12, .2)',
     lineWidth: 5
                },
                ticks : {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]    
        },
 },
    plugins : [{ // this is the magical bit :)
  afterRender : function(c, options) {
   let meta = c.getDatasetMeta(0), max;
   c.ctx.save();
            c.ctx.strokeStyle = c.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.color;
            c.ctx.lineWidth = c.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.lineWidth;
            c.ctx.beginPath();
   meta.data.forEach(function(e) 
   {
    if (max == undefined || c.config.data.datasets[0].data[e._index] > max) {
     max = c.config.data.datasets[0].data[e._index];
    }
    c.ctx.moveTo(e._model.x,meta.dataset._scale.bottom);
    c.ctx.lineTo(e._model.x,e._model.y);
            });
            c.ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
            c.ctx.textAlign = 'right';
            c.ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            c.ctx.fillText('Max value: ' + max, c.width - 10, 10);
            c.ctx.stroke();
   c.ctx.restore();
  }
 }],
 tooltips : {
            callbacks : {
                label : function(tooltipItem) {
                    console.log(tooltipItem)
                    return tooltipItem.yLabel;
                }
            }
        }        
});
```

```css
>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.6.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hello, I submitted an edit to your code by adding a code snippet, but the code worked exactly like my current.

Comment: Can you explain me more about your issue ?

Comment: Hi, there are no data label values on each point and the lines from the points do not form from the yAxis and intercept the xAxis

Comment: Hello, I am sorry, but that was not what is needed. When you check these links, then the graph should have data labels on the line and lines have to go from the xAxis along the yAxis to the data points of the line graph.

Comment: Here is the data label link: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/

Comment: Here is the yAxis to data points link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721661/chart-js-how-to-set-line-height-only-to-the-points

Comment: I need these plugins to work at the same time, if it is possible.

Comment: I update my answer, for data label I added one script for that

Comment: It is working, thank you very much. Your help has been remarkable. If you do not mind me asking one more question, then the data label numbers are at the moment, fixed inside the data points. I tried with previous attempts to anchor the numbers to different locations, so they would be normally visible, but how to do that? Also, in this link: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/ , there are data labels surrounded with small boxes, how to do so, that the data label numbers are anchored to different location and have a surrounding box?

Comment: What is mean of different location ? need some more elaboration. !

Comment: Sorry, when you look this link: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/ , then the first thing you see, is a descriptive image of the plugin. On that image, you can see the different location anchor points. The image you first see, there are many examples of the data label numbers, being in a location where they are easily visible, not inside the data point. It is under the category of Positioning when you press Get Started.

Comment: Hi, Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for helping me out. If I may ask, then can the corners of the box can be made round with some type of option?

Comment: Add borderRadius property